# How to render page once data is loaded Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular. I am trying to change the layout of the my webpage based on whether a user is logged in or logged out. However this can be done only when the 'true' of 'false' is retrieved from the server. How can I do that?
The TS code snippet is:

```
lgn: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.lgn = true;
      } else {
        this.lgn = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

The HTML code snippet is:

```
<div *ngIf="lgn; then thenBlock; else elseBlock"></div>
  <ng-template #thenBlock>Logged In</ng-template>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>Not logged in</ng-template>
```

However this always shows 'Not logged in'.

Comment: Can you share your `onAuthStateChanged` method please

Comment: The `onAuthStateChanged` method is taken from `@angular/fire` package. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#onauthstatechangedcallback-context

Comment: Have you tried to add some `console.log` into your if else statement to check if it goes into it ? And also `console.log` your user ?

Comment: The `console.log` shows `true` when logged in and `false` when logged out. However the HTML file is rendered first before data is retrieved from the server. So it is a case where not logged in is displayed first and then the boolean value is retrieved. I want it to be the other way i.e., first data is received and then page is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Route Resolver` to load the user data before you arrive at the component:

1. Implement a resolver service first:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) { }
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.auth.authState;
    }
}
```

2. Add the service to your routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'somepath',
        component: SomeComponent,
        resolve: {
            user: UserResolverService
        }
    }
];
```

3. Now you can get the data right after you arrived at the component:

```js
user: any;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.route.snapshot.data.user;
}
```

Comment: I tried the subscribe method earlier. It works fine but the problem is that the webpage loads first, then data is retrieved and then the status is changed to logged in. Is there a way such that page will be rendered only after data is retrieved?

Comment: What you want is to use router resolver which will prevent your navigation before a data is arrived.

Comment: Also you could use routing guard to archieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your server call is always returning false - I would confirm this works first using a console log...

And I'd probably write your html like this

```
<div *ngIf="lgn; else elseBlock">
Logged In
</div>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>Not logged in</ng-template>
```

Comment: I checked with `console.log`. The server returns true when user is logged in. I think this is a case where the webpage is rendered first and then data is retrieved from the system.

Comment: yes you are doing a syncronous call... you should be subscribing using rxjs and then it will work